# What is the etymology of סמאל?

Tags: hebrew, names, etymology, malach-angel

I've heard that סמאל ([Samael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samael), a "bad" angel) is related to the word שמאל (left). Is there any basis for this, and are there any other explanations for his name?

The [Hebrew Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9C&oldid=12764703) claims that it is connected to "סומא" (blindness) and "אל" (God; the suffix on many angel names), but it doesn't bring a source (it says "[דרוש מקור]").

The [Hebrew Wikitionary](https://he.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9C&oldid=120737) mentions another possibility (in addition to "סומא"), that it comes from "סם" (potion, poison), but says that neither has any proofs.

This question is looking for **academic** answers, based on reliable sources. However, more *midrashic* answers such as acronyms are also acceptable.

Comment: Inkbug, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for bringing your question here.  I look forward to your participation here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have collected the answers I and others found. Please update with any other possibilities you find.

#### Etymologies based on *reliable academic* sources

- The [Jewish Encyclopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13055-samael) brings two possible etymologies:

  1. "סם-אל" ("the venom of God") - Samael is the angel of death, who kills with a drop of poison (apparently based on [this book](https://archive.org/stream/diepaulinischea01evergoog#page/n75/mode/2up), pgs. 69 and 71 - can someone who understands German verify this?).
  2. From the "Syrian god Shemal" - apparently based on "Bousset, 'Religion,' p. 242" (I don't know what this book is). According to [The Origin ff Our Belief in God](http://langkjer.dk/origin/1-22.htm) (Erik Langkjer - does anyone know anything about this?) the name of this God comes from the word "left". This means that Samael is *indirectly* related to שמאל (Hebrew left).

#### Other Etymologies

- "סומא" (blindness) - Unsourced claim in [Hebrew Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9C&oldid=12764703) and [Hebrew Wikitionary](https://he.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9C&oldid=120737)
- Acronym of "סיום מסכת אין לעשות" - [Klauzenberger Rebbe](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18060/1705)

Comment: Why is "apparently based on" a "reliable source[]" but "I have heard in the name of the Klauzenberger Rebbe" not??

Comment: This question is looking for scientific answers. Not to disregard the Rebbe's knowledge, but I prefer more academic answers.

Comment: −1, then: poor dichotomy.

Comment: @msh210 I clarified the question and rephrased the title. I hope that is better.

Comment: @Inkbug this is not a scientific question

Comment: "Bousset, 'Religion,' p. 242" is [this book](https://archive.org/details/diereligiondesju00bousuoft/page/242/mode/2up?view=theater).

Answer (score 3):

I have heard in the name of the Klauzenberger Rebbe Zatzal that סמאל is the Malach that does all in his power that people should not make a Siyum. Therefore סמאל is ראשי תיבות

"סיום מסכת אין לעשות"

Answer (score 2):

I heard of a different explanation that סמאל is סמ אל - the potion/medicine/poison (it can be any of those depending on context) of Hashem - but I'm not 100% sure how that fits in with the part that he is a "bad" angel. ("" on the bad because really everything an angel does is what Hashem tells him to do and Hashem is the ultimate "Tov Vehameitiv")

Comment: Interesting, but I'd like something with reliable sources backing it up.

Comment: Sorry, I wish i could also, but i heard this a while ago from someone and im not sure where he got it from.

Comment: Seems to be also in Hebrew wikitionary.